# Non linear regression with one parameter

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

I need to solve the following exercise where I'm asked to find the coefficient $\beta $ of the following model $ y_i = \beta x_{i}^2 + \epsilon_{i}$ knowing only that $ E[x_{i}^2\epsilon_{i}] = 0$ and check whether is consistent. I know that it's like an exercise for kids but I don't know how to proceed because of the $x^2$. I wrote the equation for $\hat{\beta}= (X'^{2}X^{2})^{-1} (X^{2}Y) $ then I basically got stuck since I don't know how to proceed. Can someone explain me how to deal with this case and in general with non linear also for the part of consistency?? Thanks

Comment: try to think about $\tilde x_i = x_i^2$ and a vector/matrix $\tilde X$ made up of $\tilde x_i$'s. Can you now apply the existing result to that (new) model?

Comment: I guess that if I follow what you told me I should end up with the classic $\beta$. Rather, I tried to solve in vector notation and I got $ \beta = \frac {\sum \hat{x}_{i}^2 y_{i}}{\sum \hat{x}_{i}^4}$ but honestly I'm not sure this is the right result. As far as the consistency is concerned, how can I proceed to prove whether is consistent or not? Thanks for the hint anyway

Comment: What are the distribution assumptions? There are some standard theorem/results about linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

1) You said nothing about the distribution of $\epsilon$, so I will assume that the standard assumptions that the error terms are i.i.d $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ hold. This is crucial, as different assumptions may complicate the maximization of the Likelihood functions w.r.t to $\beta$. So, assuming the $i.i.d$ behavior of the noise terms, we can apply the classic OLS algorithm (the results will be the same as in the maximization problem).

2) This regression model, $y = \beta x^2+\epsilon$, is linear. The linearity of the regression model is defined w.r.t the coefficients. I.e., whether $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}y$ depends on $\beta$ or not. Hence, for all elemntary $g$, the model $y=\beta g(x) + \epsilon$ is linear.

3) As such you can simply apply the stated result $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y $ or derive it implicitly, 
\begin{align}
\min_{\beta} S(\beta) =\min_{\beta} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i^2 = \min_{\beta} \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \beta x_i^2)^2 ,
\end{align}
so taking derivative w.r.t $\beta$ and equating to $0$, you will get that 
$$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum y_i x_i^2}{\sum x_{i}^4}.
$$
Note that if you want to use the matrix notation, then $\mathrm{x} = (x_1, ..., x_n)'$ and $\mathrm{y} = (y_1, ..., y_n)'$. It will yield the same result.